# Calculating sum of squared deviations in R

Tags: r, statistics

How can I calculate the sum of squared deviations(from the mean) of a vector?

I tried using the command

> sum(x-mean(x))^2

but unfortunately what this returns is -1.998401e-15 which cannot be right. Is there a subtle operator, like a parenthesis, that I am missing here perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: `sum((x-mean(x))^2)` sum of the squares not square of the sums?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may well be correct.  -2.0 to the power of 10^15 means it is essentially zero.  But as Justin just noted in the comment, you have

```
    (sum (x - mean(x) )^2
```

when you probably meant:

```
    sum( (x - mean(x) )^2 )
```

Comment: Okay, so another set of parentheses is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, "operator precedence" is the technical term.  The squaring needs to move inside.

Comment: That works for the squared case. But what about the simple >sum(x-mean(x))? The answer should be 0 but what R returns is -1.998401e-15.

Comment: That "is" zero:  check with the `all.equal` function.  FWIW, this is [floating point error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: @Justin There are no digits here though, it has be zero identically.

Comment: @JohnK : go ahead and read R [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) ...

Answer (score 14):

You can also use another way to calculate the sum of squared deviations:

```
x <- 1:10 #an example vector

# the 'classic' approach
sum( (x - mean(x) )^2 )
# [1] 82.5

# based on the variance
var(x) * (length(x) - 1)
#[1] 82.5
```

The latter works because `var(x) = (x - mean(x))^2) / (length(x) - 1)`. This is the *sample* variance:

[image]