# How to compute summation in r

Tags: r

My R code:

```
((x[1]-xm)^2)+((x[2]-xm)^2)+((x[3]-xm)^2)+((x[4]-xm)^2)+((x[5]-xm)^2)+((x[6]-xm)^2)
```

This computation would be much easier if i formulated the problem as a summation. How do I do that in r? Something like:

```
sum((x[i]-xm)^2) for i=1 to i=6?
```

x is a data frame.

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and desired output. If `x` is a data.frame it seems odd that this would work with `x[1]` and not `x[[1]]`. Are you sure `x` isn't a vector?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385377/calculating-sum-of-squared-deviations-in-r

Comment: I would suggest you use loops. Your example is rather simple, so i would follow the instructions in this link and i think you will get your answer in no time! good luck. [link] (http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/)

Comment: @Dfinzgar loops are a terrible recommendation for this problem. All basic arithmetic is vectorized in R, so `sum((x-xm)^2)` works perfectly as Technophobe01 demonstrates.

Comment: You say `x` is a data frame, which makes your question less clear. That implies that `x[i]` is a column vector, so the question is what do you mean to sum column vectors? Do you want the overall sum? The row sums? Something else? A small reproducible example with sample data (preferably shared via simulation or `dput()`) makes everything clear. [See here for tips on asking good reproducible R questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)

Comment: @Gregor I tried loops and you are right :) Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `sum()`, example below:

```
IndexStart <- 1
x <- seq(IndexStart, 6, 1)
xm <- 1

result1 <- ((x[1]-xm)^2)+((x[2]-xm)^2)+((x[3]-xm)^2)+((x[4]-xm)^2)+((x[5]-xm)^2)+((x[6]-xm)^2)
print(result1)
# [1] 55

result2 <- sum((x-xm)^2) # <- Solution
print(result2)
# [1] 55
```

Answer (score 15):

Without reading all the responses in this thread, there is a really easy way to do summations in R.

Modify the following two lines as needed to accommodate a matrix or other type of vector:

```
i <- 0:5; sum(i^2)
```

Use `i` for your index when accessing a position in your vector/array.

Note that `i` can be any vector.